# my csv percentage count is split equal though i know its not

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

[image: output]

i have a csv file with two columns, i want to see there death percentage per year but it split the percentage equally, I'm sure it's not equal.
Here is the code:

```
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd

    # Load data
    df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Selamola\Desktop\Analysis\mixed things.csv")

    # Calculate survey results
    survey_results = df.groupby('year') \
        .amount.count()

    # Make a pie chart
    plt.pie(survey_results.values,
            labels=survey_results.index,
            autopct="%1.2f%%"
            )
    plt.title('death')
    plt.axis()

    # Paste code here:
    plt.show()
```

please help and find attached

Comment: Can you please include some lines of the expected input, as well as the specifically desired output?

Comment: What is in `amount` column?

Comment: number of deaths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an output I guess you have 10 entries for each year and the amount column is no. of death. I guess what you need is `survey_results = df.groupby('year').amount.sum()`.